# how do i pass variable to session in Laravel construct

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to have available across the system a parameter I bring from another Integrated system,  Inside my dashboard controller I get that parameter, so I can print the parameter before entering middleware. Inside middleware I get error `undefined variable body`

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Session;

class dashboardController extends Controller
{   
  protected $body;
  protected $valor;

  public function __construct(){
    $url = 'https://domain.cl/xxxxxxxxxxxxx'; 

    $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
    $result = $client->get($url);
    $body = $result->getBody(); 
    echo $body;  <--- when I print $body here I can see the value.

    $this->middleware(function($request, $next) {
        $this->valor = $request->session()->put('responsable', $body);  <-- null here
     return $next($request);
    });
  }
}
```

Then I want this session parameter available for my other constructs, how can I do this, I'm not using laravel auth. I log in using an Integrated system and pass the username. That's what Im checking against.

Thanks in advance!

the image show what i get in transfer controller, in dashboard controller i see the right value 'responsable'=>'rodrigo'.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `$body` is outside from the scope when you do

```
 $this->middleware(function($request, $next) {
      $this->valor = $request->session()->put('responsable', $body);  <-- null here
      return $next($request);
  });
```

But you can pass it with `use` :

```
 $this->middleware(function($request, $next) use ($body) {
      $this->valor = $request->session()->put('responsable', $body);
      return $next($request);
  });
```

Comment: thanks ,I forgot about that ! but how can $this->valor (or session) be available in another controller?

Comment: Since you put the $body in a session, you should be able to get the content of the session with `$watheverFromAnotherController = session('responsable');`

Comment: it only works on methods of the same controller, in another controller is null, by the way i'm using backpack crud, dashboard is extending controller, all other controllers extends crudcontroller .

Comment: If `session()->put('key', 'value');` works correctly, then your other controller should be able to retrieve the value whatever if you're using backpack or not. Does your value is set from both controllers when you dump `session()->all()` ?

Comment: i see different values as shown in the image above, where i declared the session in dashboard i see the parameter correctly, in other controller i see like in the image

Comment: Looks like the session has not been initialized yet in your second controller. Maybe I'm wrong, but I remember reading a thing about session that wasn't initialized before the middleware and that was only possible to retrieve them inside or after the middleware.

Comment: i deleted dd(session()->all()) in dashboard, now i get the hardcoded value i put in the session ('responsable', 'rodrigo'), in my transfer controller, i replace the value 'rodrigo' with the parameter $body , and i get stream again

Comment: it seems guzzle send a lot of data here  $body = $result->getBody();  print_r $body ->>GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream Object ( [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Resource id #11 [size:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => [seekable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1 [readable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1 [writable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1 [uri:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => php://temp [customMetadata:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Array ( ) )